# Kotlin: How to copy some properties between non-data classes?

Tags: kotlin

I've a third-party class in Java, from which I want to copy some properties to a Kotlin non-data class. Most properties are straight copy, a few are derived. Is there a smart way to do this other than a the mundane copy-paste? I looked into Delegates, but it didn't fit my use case.

The Java class is an implementation of [TestExecutionSummary](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.1.0/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/listeners/TestExecutionSummary.html). I'm not interested in the real implementation class, just the methods exposed by the interface.

My class:

```
@Entity
class TestExecutionSummary {
    @EmbeddedId
    lateinit var id: TestExecutionId

    lateinit var timeStarted: OffsetDateTime
    lateinit var timeFinished: OffsetDateTime
    var totalFailureCount: Long by Delegates.notNull()
    var containersFoundCount: Long by Delegates.notNull()
    var containersStartedCount: Long by Delegates.notNull()
    var containersSkippedCount: Long by Delegates.notNull()
    var containersAbortedCount: Long by Delegates.notNull()
    var containersSucceededCount: Long by Delegates.notNull()
    var containersFailedCount: Long by Delegates.notNull()
    var testsFoundCount: Long by Delegates.notNull()
    var testsStartedCount: Long by Delegates.notNull()
    var testsSkippedCount: Long by Delegates.notNull()
    var testsAbortedCount: Long by Delegates.notNull()
    var testsSucceededCount: Long by Delegates.notNull()
    var testsFailedCount: Long by Delegates.notNull()
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    var failures: List<TestFailure> = emptyList()

    @Embeddable
    class TestExecutionId {
        var id: Long by Delegates.notNull()
        var jobExecutionId: Long by Delegates.notNull()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code to share?

Comment: @s1m0nw1 I do now, please see edit

Comment: Are you looking for some "smart way" that is kotlin specific? There is always the good old BeanUtils.copyProperties if you just want to copy them dynamically.

Comment: @jingx yes. For now, I’m using Spring [BeanUtils.copyProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-), and that seems to do the job

Comment: is there any kotlin function for `copy() , toString() , hashCode(). etc`